# Does SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() insert previous rows before an error?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlcommand

I have a temp table in sql server that I have created. I have the commandText of the sqlcommand object to insert from the temp table to another table. My question is: Does it insert the rows before reaching an error row?

So for example, lets say there is 1000 rows in the temptable and 0 in tableA. I do an insert from temptable to tableA. There is an error on row 999 and an exception is thrown. Does tableA have 989 rows inside of it? Or is it 0?

I have tried googling this question, but I haven't found anything. I have also read the documentation on [SQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and haven't found an answer. I would appreciate any help or leads.

Comment: If it inserted 999 of the 1,000 rows requested in the insert statement it would violate the Atomic aspect of ACID. Which means that any sql statement is "all or nothing". If it partially inserted it would be a real mess. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480356.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `INSERT` is a single statement, then no.  There will be 0 rows in tableA.

If you had multiple statements in a batch then each sucessfully executed statement will perform the requested modifications EXCEPT the statement that errors out, which will leave the tables in the state as of the completion of the prior batch.

If you have the multiple statement batch mentioned above wrapped inside a `TRANSACTION` then, generally speaking, if one of the statements errors you can roll back the entire batch to the state prior to any of the statements executing.

Note: again, this is generally speaking.  There are many external factors that can leave your data in an inconsistent state (server failure, IO corruption, etc) in which case SQL Server will try to rollback your data from the transaction log.

This is a single statement

```
INSERT tableA (col1,col2,col3)
SELECT col1,col2,col3
FROM #tmpTable;
```

An error here (such as datatype mismatch, `NULL` value on a `NOT NULL` column, etc) will result in 0 rows being inserted into tableA.

Comment: If you do an 
insert into tableA(..) select ... from  temptable ... it will insert all of them.I am unsure if this is considered a single insert statement or multiple.

Comment: Yes, it is considered a single `INSERT` statement and will result in 0 rows inserted if there is an error.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much, I was spending a lot of time trying to figure it out!